# How to define the condition of a corrupted file for audio file in Python

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I am using Python 3.6, Jupyter notebook by connecting to a remote machine. I have a large dataset of mp3 files. I use  FFmpeg (version is 2.8.14-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.) to convert mp3 files to wav format.

My code below goes over the file path list and if the file is mp3 it converts it to wav format and deletes the mp3 file. The code works but for a few files it stops and gives error. I opened those files and saw that they have no duration and each of them has size 600 looking at the terminal folder size column but it might be a coincidence. The error is `file not found for 'temp_name.wav'`.

I can see that these corrupted files are not able to be converted to wav. When I delete them manually and run the code again it works. But I have large datasets and cannot know which files are corrupted beforehand. Is there a way to make the code (before converting the file to wav) if the file is corrupted it deletes it and continues to next file. I just don`t know how to define the condition of a corrupted file or if the file cannot be converted to wav.

```
# npaths is the list of full file paths 
for fpath in npaths:
    if (fpath.endswith(".mp3")):
        cdir=os.path.dirname(fpath)      # extract the directory of file
        os.chdir(cdir)        # change the directory to cdir
        filename=os.path.basename(fpath)   # extract the filename from the path
        os.system("ffmpeg -i {0} temp_name.wav".format(filename))
        ofnamepath=os.path.splitext(fpath)[0]    # filename without extension
        temp_name=os.path.join(cdir, "temp_name.wav")
        new_name = os.path.join(ofnamepath+'.wav')
        os.rename(temp_name,new_name) # use original filename with wav ext
        old_file = os.path.join(ofnamepath+'.mp3')    # find and delete the mp3
        os.remove(old_file)
```

Comment: The analysis will need full decoding. Either do that with for example ffmpegs dummy output (search docs) while checking the executable return state or probably more simple: just check if output was produced and skip if not. Real exception handling would be more robust, but is probably not needed

Comment: thank you Sascha for your time. I have read your comment several times but I think my programming background at least in Python is not enough to create a solution from your comment, so I still need help.